# How can I use a variable that declared in an if statement outside the if?

Tags: java

How can I use a variable that I declared inside an `if` statement outside the `if` block?

```
if(z<100){
    int amount=sc.nextInt();
}

while(amount!=100)
{ //this is wrong.it says we cant find amount variable ?
    something
}
```

Comment: Learn more about variable scope: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm

Answer (score 8):

The scope of `amount` is bound inside the curly braces and so you can't use it outside.

The solution is to bring it outside of the if block (note that `amount` will not get assigned if the if condition fails):

```
int amount;

if(z<100){

    amount=sc.nextInt();

}

while ( amount!=100){  }
```

Or perhaps you intend for the while statement to be inside the if:

```
if ( z<100 ) {

    int amount=sc.nextInt();

    while ( amount!=100 ) {
        // something
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work because the amount variable isn't always assigned, other answer is better.

Comment: @EdC it is hard to say what "actually" will work without understanding the OP's problem. Hopefully this answer illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use `amount` in the outer scope you need to declare it outside the `if` block:

```
int amount;
if (z<100){
    amount=sc.nextInt();
}
```

To be able to read its value you also need to ensure that it is assigned a value in all paths. You haven't shown how you want to do this, but one option is to use its default value of 0.

```
int amount = 0;
if (z<100) {
    amount = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Or more concisely using the conditional operator:

```
int amount = (z<100) ? sc.nextInt() : 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

you cant, its only confined to the if block.either make its scope more visible, like declare it outside if and use it within that scope.

```
int amount=0;
if ( z<100 ) {

amount=sc.nextInt();

}

while ( amount!=100 ) { // this is right.it will now find amount variable ?
    // something
}
```

check [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) about variable scopes in java